# SQL Server 2008  - one table 24gb, deleted 95% of that data, whats the best way to regain space?

Tags: sql-server-2008

We were saving unnecessary logging data in our database. One table grew to 1 million records, 99% of that is now gone.

We have db size of 40gb and freespace of 24gb.

Whats the best way to regain that space (and consequently reduce the size of our back ups).

Our recovery mode is simple.  Can we just use the auto shrink setting in management studio ?

***Edit***

Probably worth noting that there was no need to shrink the DB to reduce the size of backup. Just removing the data is good enough. Our backups are now 9gb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, right click the database -> tasks -> shrink -> database.

Comment: lol, its auto shrink that I should avoid right. ? I don't need to detach or anything ?

Comment: Normally, shrinking a production db has consequences. Brent Ozar is likely to appear from nowhere and slap you upside the head. But what were talking about here is a change in the nature of application, so I think it's warranted.

Comment: Yep, no need to detach or anything like that.  Always make sure you have backups just as with anything else.